# How re-adjust SKNodes base on user location

Tags: ios, swift, core-location, arkit

I'm currently using ARKit and CoreLocation together to place elements on screen. Those elements (for example a building, house etc) are place base on their own coordinates (longitude/latitude) and the user coordinates. As you know, even by setting the best accuracy, CoreLocation are not always precise and the user location and heading direction are being corrected often.

When the heading direction or user location has been corrected, how can I re-adjust everything without having to remove and re-add all the Node? Seems like you cannot change the camera translation property. I also tried `setWorldOrigin(relativeTransform: simd_float4x4)` but it didn't change anything.

The best solution I found so far it's to use SKAction but if you have a lot nodes, it tends to be very expensive and slow down the app.

Can you tell me if I'm doing anything wrong or there is simpler way to do it?

Answer (score 1):

Let's consider that the physical location of only the user changes, everything else is placed relatively to the other objects. For this reason I would suggest you set the parent to all of your nodes to be a common node, that can be added as a child of the default root.

so your structure would be

`rootNode -> myRootNode -> (all other 3D)`

this way you can update the translation of `myRootNode` and it will shift all of its children into place.